# php5-embed does not load extensions

Tags: ubuntu, php

While setting up php on my Ubuntu server (using php5-embed under uwsgi/nginx), I noticed curl.so was not being loaded. The file `/etc/php5/embed/conf.d/20-curl.ini` exists and contains extension=curl.so.

Looking at `phpinfo()`, it doesn't show that any files in the conf.d directory are being loaded. The php.ini path shows up as `/etc/php5/embed/php.ini`, so everything seems to be in the right place.

What is the mechanism behind which php-embed loads extensions?

Comment: Do you see the following anywhere in your `phpinfo()` output: `Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php5/embed/conf.d`?

Comment: no, that just says (none). I've tried setting the environment variable `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` to `/etc/php5/embed/conf.d`, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Is the variable `extension_dir` set to anything in your `php.ini` file? You might try setting that.

Comment: Interesting, in phpinfo() it has extension_dir set to `/usr/lib/php5/20121212` (though it's not set to that anywhere explicitly).  [Here's my full phpinfo()](https://rawgit.com/bendavis78/0e53c54c3e683a9d78c8/raw/aa5d9cb916596e361a48c1322cf7b73e0ad95eb5/gistfile1.html).

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly set `extension_dir` to `./` or `/etc/php5/embed/`? That _should_ force php to load all your extensions.

Comment: I just tried setting `extension_dir` to `./`, `/etc/php5/embed`, and `/etc/php5/embed/conf.d`, but it still doesn't seem to work. No curl section in `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25579/discussion-between-datuser-and-ben-davis).